# how to write css animation for text typing?

Tags: css, animation

```
<sytle>
.typing{
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
white-space:nowrap;
overflow:hidden;
-webkit-animation: type 2s steps(50, end) alternate;
animation: type 2s steps(50, end) alternate;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes type{
from { width: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes type{
from { width: 0;  }
}
<style>
<div id="top" class="header">
<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="typing"  >
<b>Find anything for your Business Instantly</b>
<b>Source >> Supply >> Grow your Business Online</b>
<b>Create your Home &amp; Global website online</b>
    </h1>        
</div>
</div>
```

i have 3 bold tags which is in h1 tag, here it should display in one line, As one after another  bold tag as shown in the link [see this link   :](http://www.indiamart.com/) http://www.indiamart.com/

Please can anyone help me.

Comment: I think you'l need a **letter** selector, which isn't available in CSS. You should probably try a js solution.

Answer (score 1):

Original code by [Lea Verou](http://lea.verou.me/2011/09/pure-css3-typing-animation-with-steps/)

```css
@-webkit-keyframes typing {
    from { width: 0 }
    to { width:16.3em }
}

@-moz-keyframes typing {
    from { width: 0 }
    to { width:16.3em }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink-caret {
    from, to { border-color: transparent }
    50% { border-color: black }
}

@-moz-keyframes blink-caret {
    from, to { border-color: transparent }
    50% { border-color: black }
}

body { font-family: Consolas, monospace; }

h1 { 
    font-size:150%;
    width:16.3em;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-right: .1em solid black;
    
    -webkit-animation: typing 17s steps(30, end), /* # of steps = # of characters */
                        blink-caret 1s step-end infinite;
    -moz-animation: typing 17s steps(30, end), /* # of steps = # of characters */
                        blink-caret 1s step-end infinite;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a css typewriter</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but here i need three b tags  and it should override one another.  And i already tried this

Comment: I don't think it is a typewriter effect in your link.
This is just a `div` with `overflow:hidden` and
a with animation on it, i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Keyframes** to add typing animation to html elements.

```css
.text { 
 font: bold 200% Consolas;
 border-right: .1em solid black;
 width: 28ch;
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 30px;
 -webkit-animation: type 4s steps(28, end),
 blink-caret .4s step-end infinite alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes type { from { width: 0; } }
@-webkit-keyframes blink-caret { 50% { border-color: transparent; } }
```

```html
<p class="text">Stay Hungry ! Stay Foolish !</p>
```

See Demo here :- http://codingflag.in/mysketch.php?sketch=6